# Last CardView is not showing properly in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-cardview, drawerlayout

I am trying to display cardViews on drawerLayout something like this:
[CardView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ValHv.png)

But the last CardView is not showing properly.
My cardView.xml code looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView   
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                                                       
  xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_margin="10dp"
  card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
  card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Drinks"
        android:id="@+id/posTxt"
        android:padding="10dp"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ghost"
        android:layout_below="@+id/posTxt"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGreen"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"

        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text=" This is the best drink"
        android:id="@+id/descTxt"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />



</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and my activity_main.xml code looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawyerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.hasan.tablayout.MainActivity">


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">



        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>




    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>



    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"/>




</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I added card_view:cardCornerRadius , card_view:cardElevation in my xml code. But i don't understand where is my mistake?

Comment: What does it mean "Not showing properly"? What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: Look at the image I given. All of the cardViews except the last cardView is showing all the contents. But the last cardView is not showing all the contents.Some contents are missing.

Comment: Please share what you need in image or more description.

Comment: I gave an image at the start of my question. There all the cardViews except the last cardView display textview,imageview,textview,textview accordingly. But last two textviews of last cardview is missing.What can i do now?

Comment: Are you talking about problem like this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679445/content-going-behind-navigation-bar ?

Comment: yes,something like that..